# Redirect to child named outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following router configuration on my Angular 5 project:

```
{
    path: 'foo',
    component: FooComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':barId',
            component: BarComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    redirectTo: 'baz',
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                },
                {
                    path: 'baz',
                    component: BazComponent,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: '',
                            redirectTo: '', // Need to redirect to (qux:0)
                            pathMatch: 'full'
                        },
                        {
                            path: '0',
                            outlet: 'qux',
                            component: QuxComponent
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is configure the router so that when a user enters the `/foo/:barId/baz` it gets redirected to `/foo/:barId/baz/(qux:0)`.

Is it possible to do this within the router configuration?